# How can i write a public class that connect with database in netbeans?

Tags: java, database, netbeans, database-connection, resultset

I have to view rows of database by previous and next buttons in jFrame.
So I using resultset methods `rs.next(`) and rs.prvious() this codes are fine but i don't know how to make a separate class for database connection that connect to database when jFrame start to run .now i written entire code for create connection and move forward /backward methods inside those buttons(forward and backward buttons)  so each time i press forward or backward button it will start to create a new connection and show only first row of database .to traverse i have to initially connect with database and i have to remove database create connection code from those buttons how it is possible? my code inside forward button given below

```
   private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

//Here each time button press it newly create a connection i want to avoid that
// I want to connect with database when jFrame start to run 
//Checking Driver

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
e.printStackTrace();
 }
try
{
 String s1 ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/store";
 String user1="root";
 String pass="root";
 Statement stmt;
 ResultSet rs;
 Connection con;
 con=DriverManager.getConnection(s1, user1, pass);
 String q5 ="SELECT p_id,p_name,p_cata,p_brand,real_price,p_price,p_qty FROM PRODUCTS";
 stmt=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
 rs=stmt.executeQuery(q5);
   if (rs == null)
{
 System.out.println("sorry no data");
}
if (rs!=null)
{
 if(rs.next())
{

//assigning values to strings from 
 String x0 =rs.getString("p_id");
 String x1 =rs.getString("p_name");
 String x2 =rs.getString("p_cata");
 String x3=rs.getString("p_brand");
   Float xs5=rs.getFloat("real_price");
   String x5= Float.toString(xs5);
  Float xs6=rs.getFloat("p_price");
  String x6 =Float.toString(xs6);
  int xs7 =rs.getInt("p_qty");
  String x7 =Integer.toString(xs7);
//set values to jlabel
  jLabel13.setText(x0);
  jLabel15.setText(x1);
   jLabel17.setText(x2);
  jLabel19.setText(x3);
jLabel21.setText(x5);
  jLabel23.setText(x6);
 jLabel27.setText(x7);
            }
            else{
                rs.previous();
                jLabel8.setText("End of Database");
            }
            }

}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: you can create a separate class and make connections in its construtor

Comment: @A5l-lE5 can you show me an example please :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can connect to the DB once, store the **ResultSet** data in a **Collection** and every time you press the back/forward buttons, you show only the part of the **Collection** you need.

Regarding the connection aspect, check my code [here](https://github.com/vasouv/DietOnJava/blob/master/src/dietonjava/foodhandling/FoodSQL.java) to see what I've done and if it's helpful to you.

Then, in my main screen I just create a BlahSQL object that handles the SQL queries to the DB.